# Access G+ Communities from a Person

Tags: android, google-plus

I want to authenticate users by their membership in a closed community in G+

Is there a way to get:

1. The communities of a user
2. The members within a community

Both ways would be fine.

I am through the whole documentation (which isn't that much) and haven't found a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no support for communities as part of the Plus API right now.

You may wish to star [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=562) since it is tracking related feature requests.

Comment: Ok ... tank you. I'll do that.